# Get a reverse iterator from a forward iterator without knowing the value type

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator

I'm trying to implement some STL-style sorting algorithms. The prototype for `std::sort` looks something like this (from [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)):

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last );
```

The function is generally called like this (although the container type can vary):

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
// Populate myVec
std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
```

I duplicated the prototype of `std::sort` for my own sorting function. To iterate through the container to be sorted, I do the following:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void mySort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) {  
  RandomAccessIterator iter;
  for (iter = first; iter != last; ++iter) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Easy enough. But what if I want to use a reverse iterator? This would be convenient in algorithms that sort a container from both ends, e.g. [cocktail sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort).

Is there any way to get a reverse iterator from the iterators that are passed in as parameters? If I knew the container type in advance, I could do something like this:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void mySort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) {
  std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator riter(last);
  std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator rend(first);
  for ( ; riter != rend; ++riter) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I *don't* know the container type. What I really need to do is something like this:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void mySort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) {
  RandomAccessIterator riter = reverse_iterator(last);
  RandomAccessIterator rend = reverse_iterator(begin);
  for ( ; riter != rend; ++riter) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Is there some way to do this without having to pass in reverse iterators as additional parameters (which would solve the problem, but make the function prototype less intuitive)?

Note that I need both forward *and* reverse iterators in my implementation, so calling the function this way

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
// Populate myVec
mySort(myVec.rbegin(), myVec.rend());
```

will not work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The STL has `std::reverse_iterator<Iterator>`:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void mySort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) 
{
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<RandomAccessIterator> RIter;
  RIter riter(last);
  RIter rend(first);
  for ( ; riter != rend; ++riter) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

An [important note](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/):

> Notice however that when an iterator
>   is reversed, the reversed version does
>   not point to the same element in the
>   range, but to the one preceding it.
>   This is so, in order to arrange for
>   the past-the-end element of a range:
>   An iterator pointing to a past-the-end
>   element in a range, when reversed, is
>   changed to point to the last element
>   (not past it) of the range (this would
>   be the first element of the range if
>   reversed). And if an iterator to the
>   first element in a range is reversed,
>   the reversed iterator points to the
>   element before the first element (this
>   would be the past-the-end element of
>   the range if reversed).

Comment: I saw this in the docs earlier but gave up on it when I couldn't get anything with `reverse_iterator<IteratorType>` to compile. The problem: I forgot to add `std::` (doh!) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The `important note` is indeed important. `riter` will physically point to the element _after_ last (in a forward iterating sense). However, somewhat counterintuitively, `*riter` _does_ point to the same element as `last`.

Comment: When you assign `riter` and `rend`, you use `reverse_iterator`. What is this? Is it `std::reverse_iterator`? The latter is a class, and you have to provide a template parameter, so the code is invalid as is. Or is it a function defined by you?

Comment: It's a typo. Fixed now!

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant the parameter `first` to be `begin`?

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14, we have access to `std::make_reverse_iterator`, which will convert the (bidirectional) iterator it receives as a parameter to a  `std::reverse_iterator`. Also note that as rlbond explains in their answer, the newly created `std::reverse_iterator` will point to the preceding element of the range. [Here's a link to the cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator).

Example usage & comparison with manual creation is demonstrated below:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

auto two_pos = std::begin(a)+1;
auto five_pos = std::end(a)-2;
std::for_each(two_pos, five_pos, [](int x) { std::cout << x << ','; });

std::cout << '\n';

auto reverse_two_pos = std::make_reverse_iterator(two_pos);
auto automatic_reverse_five_pos = std::make_reverse_iterator(five_pos);
std::reverse_iterator<decltype(five_pos)> manual_reverse_five_pos(five_pos);

std::for_each(automatic_reverse_five_pos, reverse_two_pos, [](int x) { std::cout << x << ','; });
std::cout << '\n';
std::for_each(manual_reverse_five_pos, reverse_two_pos, [](int x) { std::cout << x << ','; });
```

Output:

```
2,3,4,
4,3,2,
4,3,2,
```

Answer (score -5):

Check out the base() method of reverse_iterator.

Comment: That gets you the forward iterator (the _reverse_ of what this question is asking)