# Is storing iterators inside this class unwise? How else to iterate through this sequence?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator

Warning this is a long question!

I am implementing a Solitaire card game in C++ on Win32, and after asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037867/can-i-convert-a-reverse-iterator-to-a-forward-iterator) question, it's becoming clear that I may need a bit of guidance regarding actual class design rather than implementation details.

I am using a model view Controller pattern to implement the game. The model is the game, cards, columns and move history. The view is responsible for painting to screen and the control responsible for handling messages and the timer.

The aspect of the game that I am currently trying to implement is the Action history, which belongs to the `Model` - I want to be able to "undo" and "redo" any `Action`.

I describe a `Move` object as an atomic move of a single card from one `CardPile` to another. And I described an `Action` as consisting of one or more `Moves`. e.g. a deal will be 10 `Moves` from the `Deck` to a particular `Column`. ( `Deck` and `Column` are simply specializations of `CardPile`).

I define the Action as a deque of Moves,  and have provided some functions to GetCurrentMove() and to Advance() a move when it has been performed.

```
class Action
{
 public:
    void SetMoves( std::deque<Move> dmoves){ _m_deque = dmoves; }
    void Advance();
    std::deque<Move>::const_iterator GetCurrentMove();
 private:
    std::deque<Move> _m_deque;
    std::deque<Move>::const_iterator currentmove;
};
```

When dealing (or setting up, or undoing), these `Move` objects are data for an animation. I need to be able to access a single `Move` object at a time. I retrieve the `Move`, parse it into x,y co-ords and then kick off an animation to move a card from one place to another on screen. When the card has reached its destination, I then pull another `Move` from the deque.

I have been advised by others with more experience, not to store iterators inside the `Action` class. The STL doesn't do this and there are good reasons apparently.

But my question is - don't I *have* to store iterators inside the `Action` class?
You see both my Model and View need access to the current `Move`, so where else can I store that iterator that refers to the current `Move` ... inside the Controller?

My game animation is based (very broadly) on this model:

```
void control.game_loop( message )
{
   switch( message )
   {
      case TIMER:
      {
          if( view.CardHasReachedDestination() )
          {
             game.AdvanceAnimation();
             if( !game.AnimationFinished() )
                 view.Parse(game.GetNextMove());
          }
          view.MoveCardXY();
          view.PaintToTheScreen();
          controller.StartTheTimerAgain();
      }
   }
}
```

Best wishes,

BeeBand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function template to animate an entire Action, not just one Move at a time. Invoke that with beginning and ending iterators for the Action that needs to be animated:

```
template <class iterator>
void animate_action(iterator first, iterator last) { 
    for (iterator i=first; i!=last; ++i)
        animate_move(*i);
}
```

Where `animate_move` is pretty much what you already had for showing the animation of a single move. You'd invoke this with something like:

```
animate_action(action.begin(), action.end());
```

or to animate in reverse order:

```
animate_action(action.rbegin(), action.rend());
```

This is (a large part of) why you want to make animate_action a template -- this way it neither knows nor cares whether it receives a forward iterator or a reverse_iterator.

Edit: Based on the further comments, there seem to be a few alternatives.

The standard stand-by would be to use a separate thread to handle the animated drawing, so it would just have something like:

```
while (current_position != final_position) {
    draw_card(currrent_position);
    current_position = next_position();
    sleep(timer_period);
}
```

Another would be rather than waiting for a timer to fire, and requesting the current iterator at that point, I'd tend to create and queue up an object representing each move in the animation, then when the timer fires, the timer function retrieves and executes the next item in the queue:

```
for (int i=0;i<Move.size(); i++)
    for (int j=0; j<num_positions; j++)
       enqueue(move, Move[i], position(j));
```

Comment: But surely to animate in reverse order you need to do more than animate the series of actions in reverse order - each action itself also has to be reversed.

Comment: @Autopulated:I mentioned reverse iterators only because in his previous question he'd asked about forward and reverse iterators. You're right that to actually reverse the animation (e.g. to undo a move) you'd also need to reverse each individual animation.

Comment: @Both: re. reverse animation. Yes on the 'undo' I have a function view.ParseUnMove(), as opposed to ParseMove(), which reverses the source and destination `CardPiles` - this creates a reverse animation.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: I see what you mean about creating a function that uses a range of iterators retrieved from the class. However, in the game, animation ( and thus the for loop you describe above) is tightly controlled by the timer messages. So effectively, each timer message invokes a tiny incremental step _within_ "animate_move()", and once that Move has been animated, the iterator i can advance, until the whole Action is complete. The problem still boils down to needing to query the value of iterator i - (which `Move` we're on needs to be stored somewhere) on receipt of a timer message.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list instead of a deque, then the iterators pointing to an element will remain valid for the lifetime of the element.

If you do that, I don't see anything wrong with storing iterators in this case.