# using base() to convert reverse_iterator to (forward) iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a sorted std::vector and I have to using the reverse_iterator for searching. It does return me the reverse_iterator for the element I search for. But I need to know the corresponding the forward iterator in the vector. I search the stackoverflow and it shows several posts that people recommend to use base() for conversion

```
vector<double>::reverse_iterator rit = std::upper_bound(sortData.rbegin(), sortData.rend(), 0.3);

cout << "the element in the vector with reverse iterator is " << *rit << endl;
```

However, in the post I found, people said to tell the corresponding forward iterator, I need to use (rit+1).base() instead of rit.base(), I don't understand why. If I do that way, I can't retrieve the same element. So I use rit.base() instead, so is it right?

```
vector< double >::iterator it=rit.base();
cout << "the element in the vector with forward iterator is " << *it << endl;
```

Comment: No, add one before `.base`, or subtract one after and remember to check for `end` before.  It is a quirk of how reverse iterator is implemented and the valid addresses near an array (one before begin is not valid)

Comment: but if I access the element by (rit+1).base(), it doesn't return the element I expected.

Comment: @user18285419 give a simple, complete, compiling example that demonstrates your problem (not a code snippet that is incomplete, or an overly complex code dump).  http://sscce.org Also note that `upper_bound` returns the one-past-the-end element in the passed range: `upper_bound( rbegin, rend ).base()` is equivalent to `lower_bound( begin, end )`, but `*upper_bound( rbegin, rend)` != `*lower_bound( begin, end )`.

Comment: I am so sorry. I don't know why, but I run my testing code again. I figure out I should use (rit+1).based() to get the right answer. I apologize the first few time when I compile the code, it doesn't give me the right answer but it is fine now :(

Comment: Closed as a dupe. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2037917/514235), for why to use *"(rit+1).base() instead of rit.base()"*.