# Why do I get the error 'vector iterators incompatible'?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, iterator, std-function

I am writing a small UI for my program. I have the method `onMouseMotion()`, which I can call in one of two ways (see code); if I call it through `std::function`, then `!=` operator in the for loop stop condition produces the run-time exception `vector iterators incompatible`. Why?

```
class Widget : public EventHandler
{
protected:
    /* ... */
    std::vector<Widget *> children_;                        
    std::function<bool(Event &)> func_;

private:
    bool onMouseMotion(Event &event);
    /* ... */   
};

Widget::Widget() 
{
    /* ... */
    func_ = std::bind(&Widget::onMouseMotion, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    /* ... */
}

bool Widget::processEvent(Event &event)
{
    if (event.getType() == ui::EventType::MouseMotionEvent) {

        /* Method 1 - onMouseMotion works ok */     
        onMouseMotion(event);

        /* Method 2 - onMouseMotion throws */
        //func_(event);

        return true;
    }
}

bool Widget::onMouseMotion(Event &event)
{
    /* exception occurs on the next line, only when using Method 2 above */
    for (auto child = children_.rbegin(); child != children_.rend(); ++child) {}
}
```

**Updates**:

- program is single-threaded.
- the exception is thrown when entering the `for` loop, zero iterations occur.
- compiling with MSVC.
- same exception with an empty `for` loop.
- rewritten examples to illustrate the `std::function` problem.

Comment: Can `children_` vector be modified by something from another thread? If it can, than the answer is simple: vector reallocates and iterator becomes invalid. Use `std::list` instead of vector then.

Comment: Nope, my program is single-threaded.

Comment: how many times is it looping before the exception is thrown ?

Comment: And `(*hovered_)->processEvent` does not modify the vector either?

Comment: How is `howered_` initialized before the first call to `onMouseMotion`? If it is not, you cannot use it in comparisons without incurring UB.

Comment: hovered_ is irrelevant, the program doesn't get there.

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi zero times. The exception is thrown when entering the for loop.

Comment: did you try using a debugger, putting a break point at before you enter the loop and check the values of the iterators and length of the vector ?

Comment: @TsarIoann - no, it doesn't modify it. The vector is actually `protected` (I corrected the q.)

Comment: What happens if you replace `auto child` with `std::vector<Widget *>::reverse_iterator child = children_.rbegin();`?  Probably irrelevant, but the line `hovered_ = child.base();` should have produced a compilation error, too.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy - the program is not doing any comparisons with `hovered_` before throwing.

Comment: did you try removing `auto` and put the explicit type instead ?

Comment: same thing with explicit type instead of `auto` :(

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis It should not have produced compilation error, cause conversion is done. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2037917/1565832

Comment: I think it's time to name the compiler that you are using.

Comment: Good point, it's MSVC.

Comment: did you try using an index based loop instead of iterators ? 
(at least it is work around till you find out what is wrong )

Comment: no, and I will stick with iterators because I want to find out what is wrong :D

Comment: Do you initialize hovered_ somewhere?

Comment: @PBrandoli: I guess it is irrelevant since the exception is being thrown before entering the body of the loop

Comment: Anyway, yes, `hovered_` is initialized to `children_.end()` in the class constructor.

Comment: I have heard of some bugs in MSVC when using [auto keyword](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779867/assertion-vector-iterators-incompatible-fails-when-using-auto-keywork-with-vector-iterator). For the time being you can replace auto with type required until you can find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @MohitJain: he is getting the error even with the explict type

Comment: @DanNestor: would you please try to remove the body of the loop, throw  a simple printing statement and try it, is it still throwing the exception like that ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Sorry I missed the conversation. Looked at the question just now. @Dan Does the same problem occur even if you use `bool onMouseMotion(Event &event) const;`? Can you remove the condition from `for loop` and print the [types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/) of `child` and `children_.rend()`? You would need to enable RTTI if not already enabled.

Comment: Same thing happenning with empty `for` loop body.

Comment: Is it possible that onMouseMotion is called on a Widget object that has been deallocated?

Comment: @DanNestor Can you [print the type](http://ideone.com/bMS85r) of `child` and `children_.rend()`?

Comment: `typeid.name()` is identical, namely `class std::reverse_iterator<class std::_Vector_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<struct std::_Simple_types<class ui::Widget *> > > >` for both `child` and `children_.rend()`.

Comment: ok, I managed to eliminate the exception with a workaround, updating question now.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but can you use [std::rbegin and std::rend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin)

Comment: @DanNestor Which workaround did you use to make it work?

Comment: I once investigated similar 'mysterious' effect (a program ran perfectly well in Release but stumbled into the assertion in Debug). Eventually, I found out that the contents of object containing the container in question was `memset`'ted to 0 in the constructor. That destroyed its internal structures, and thence all iterators obtained from that container were considered by the run-time check procedures to be having 'singular values'.

Comment: I updated the question. The problem only occurs if I call the method through a `std::function`. Any ideas? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Run your program and when RTL shows you the assertion, click 'Retry' to switch to the debugger. The top stack frame is likely to be `std::_Debug_message`, switch to the frame immediately underneath it. You must then find yourself in `std::_Vector_const_iterator::_Compat`. Inspect `this->_Myproxy` and `this->_Myproxy->_Mycont`. They both must be not null, and the latter must point to your vector. If that is not so, you have somewhere caused corruption to your vector object.

Comment: Does `EventHandler` inherit from `Event`?

Comment: @MohitJain no, it doesn't

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy looks like `child` is corrupt somehow, in my Watch window it says "unable to read memory". I wasn't able to find the frames you mentioned.

Comment: Could this be an access problem? By accessing my method through the functor, does the access level change? I'm thinking no, since `onMouseMotion` is private.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, there was some confusion. Once you have given your address (to a functor or to anybody else), there is nothing like private, static etc.

Comment: [This works](http://ideone.com/kL0Lfo). So there is no restriction like public, private.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54722/discussion-between-dan-nestor-and-mohit-jain).

Comment: I found the problem - initializing an object with `obj({x, y})` instead of `obj(x, y)` cleared the error. I don't quite understand though why the compiler let me do that.

Comment: Your class does not seem to have a custom copy ctor, move ctor and assignment-operators. If there's any copy/move, the captured `this` might refer to another object. E.g. `auto w = Widget();` w/o copy/move elision

Answer (score 3):

So it is clear that

- `auto` defines an iterator type for child, determined statically by the compiler (it cannot change between calls).
- the type of `child` is assignment compatible with `rbegin()` and `rend()`
- the type of `child` is relational operator compatible with `rbegin()` when called directly, but not when called through the `bind()` wrapper
- since the type of `child` cannot change, the type of `rend()` must have, in the second case.

I see the following possibilities.

1. The vector is a member and therefore the iterator type will be a pointer to member, and pointer to member has some restrictions on how it may be used.
2. The value of `this` in the first case might be different from that captured in the bind (base class vs derived class, for example)
3. The value of `this` may be delivered via a wrapper, which changes its type behaviour.

On balance, this is most likely to be an MSVC bug. The code as supplied does not compile and I am reluctant to try to modify and likely not be able to reproduce the bug. If you can post a repro case that compiles, I'd be happy to investigate further and update the answer.