# Get index in vector from reverse iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, find, reverse-iterator

I know how to get the index from a vector iterator, by subtracting the begin iterator from it. For example:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x);
size_t position = it - vec.begin();
```

However, now I want to find the index of the last `x` in the vector. How can I get the real index from the reverse iterators? I've found the following that seems to work (edit: it doesn't) but maybe there is a better (more idiomatic or whatever..) way.

```
vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = find(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), x);
size_t position = vec.size() - (it - vec.rbegin());
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037867/can-i-convert-a-reverse-iterator-to-a-forward-iterator

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto rit = std::find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 3);
    if (rit != v.rend()) {
        auto idx = std::distance(begin(v), rit.base()) - 1;
        std::cout << idx;
    } else
        std::cout << "not found!";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cff456b9f485ea1).

The reason for the `-1` in the distance computation is because of the conversion between reverse and regular iterators in the `.base()` member:

**24.5.1 Reverse iterators [reverse.iterators]**

> 1 Class template reverse_iterator is an iterator adaptor that iterates
>   from the end of the sequence defined by its underlying iterator to the
>   beginning of that sequence. The fundamental relation between a reverse
>   iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the
>   identity: `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`.

**Note**: you could also use the above code without the check for `v.rend()`, and use the convention that `idx == -1` is equivalent to an element that is not found. However, that loses the ability to do `v[idx]`, so eventually you would need a check against that as well.

Comment: My idx is unsigned. When value isn't found, distance returns -1 and overflows to big number. But I can compare this to >= size to see if it wasn't found. Is this safe?

Comment: @NeilKirk, Yeah, you'll have to deal with that separately. Using `std::prev` on `.rend().base()` is undefined behaviour AFAIK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998519/how-to-convert-reverse-iterator-into-forward-iterator-when-it-is-rend

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

`container.size() - 1 - (iterator - container.rbegin())`

or

`container.size() - 1 - std::distance(container.rbegin(), iterator)`

More info about reverse iterators. [How To Use Reverse Iterators Without Getting Confused](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-to-use-reverse-iterators-without-get/240168652). To convert reverse iterators into forward iterators and much more.

Comment: This works, but if value isn't found it gives an overflowing value. That's fine for me to test it was found, but it is safe?

Comment: The problem is when container.size() == 0, when the value is not found would give you the index that would have .end(), i think it's pretty similar to iterators end(), the index would be == .size().

Answer (score 4):

I would change TemplateRex's answer to use only reverse iterators, thus avoiding any headache with reverse-forward conversions.

```
int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto rit = std::find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 3);
    if (rit != v.rend()) {
        auto idx = std::distance(rit, v.rend()) - 1;
        std::cout << idx;
    } else
        std::cout << "not found!";
}
```

The `-1` is still needed because the first element of the vector (index 0) is actually at `v.rend() - 1`.