# How to convert reverse iterator into forward iterator when it is rend?

Tags: c++

The normal way to convert from reverse to forward iterator is

`std::prev(r_it.base())`

Is this valid when `r_it` is the same as `rend()`?
If not, how to safely convert any reverse iterator to forward iterator, where result of `rend()` converts to result of `end()`

Comment: At worst case, if you detect this condition, you just use `begin()`.

Comment: When the container is random access: `container.begin() + (rev_it - container.rbegin())`, this would convert `rbegin` in `begin`, `rend` in `end` and in between too, you could use `std::advance` for other container instead of `+`, noting the performance cost.