# Efficiently remove last element from std::list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl, std

This seems like a simple problem, and it is certainly doable, but I'd like to do it efficiently.

**The Objective**:
Remove the last element from a std::list if it meets a condition.

**The Problem**:
My compiler (MSVC++ 10) is unhappy about casting a reverse iterator to a const iterator for a method call to std::list.erase(). The message is:

> ```
> error C2664: 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>
>  std::list<_Ty>::erase(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>)' : cannot
>  convert parameter 1 from 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>' to
>  'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'
> ```

**The Code I Tried**:

```
std::list<mytype> mylist;

// lots of code omitted for clarity
bool ends_badly = true;

while(ends_badly && mylist.size() > 0)
{
    auto pos = mylist.crbegin(); // Last element in the list
    if ((*pos)->Type() == unwanted)
    {
        mylist.erase(pos); // Here is where the compiler complains
    }
    else
    {
        ends_badly = false;
    }
}
```

I can get around this by using forward iterators and looping through the list to the end, but that's so cumbersome. The compiler is OK with a forward iterator in this context, and I tried casting a the reverse iterator to a const iterator but the compiler didn't like that either.

Erasing a list element from a bidirectional list using a reverse iterator seems like a reasonable thing. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: You can call `base()` on a reverse iterator, but you need to take care of the correct offsetting yourself.

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you elaborate? I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable about iterators to know how to use your suggestion.

Comment: I might be missing a subtext here, [but why not `pop_back`?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back)

Comment: Umm, I may have been missing the obvious. I'll try that.

Comment: in addition to what @user4581301 says, you can use `remove_if` with the `back` iterator.

Comment: also why would you use a const iterator if you actually need to modify the list?

Comment: FWIW, "ForwardIterator" has a meaning, and it isn't "iterator that isn't a reverse iterator"

Comment: @BradAllred By the time I posted the question, I used `crbegin()` because I was just trying to get past what appeared to be a casting problem. I had already tried `rbegin()`. I'm just learning to use `std::list` and hadn't been aware of the much simpler solution of just using the `back()` method. I'm updating some Windows code that had originally used `CObList` and made the mistake of trying to do it line by line instead of logical blocks at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose that you can simplify your code snippet doing it the next way:

```
while (!mylist.empty() && mylist.back()->Type() == unwanted) {
    mylist.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: `mylist.back()->Type() == unwanted` is even simpler.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the specific error in your code [Can I convert a reverse iterator to a forward iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037867/can-i-convert-a-reverse-iterator-to-a-forward-iterator)

```
mylist.erase((pos+1).base());
```

Using [std::reverse_iterator::base](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base)

> The `base` iterator refers to the element that is next (from the `std::reverse_iterator::iterator_type` perspective) to the element the `reverse_iterator` is currently pointing to.

Anyway, `pop_back` is the best choice in your case.