# One variable for either iterator or reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, stdvector, reverse-iterator

I want to iterate through some `std::vector`s in a for loop but depending on some conditions, the vectors shall be iterated either forward or backward. I thought, I could easily do it by using either normal iterators or reverse iterators like this:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
        bool reverse = true;
        std::iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, int> it, end_it;

        if (reverse) {
          it = vec.rbegin();
          end_it = vec.rend();
        } else {
          it = vec.begin();
          end_it = vec.end();
        }

        for (; it != end_it; it++) {
            cout << *it << ", ";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

But unfortunately `vector::begin()` and `vector::rbegin()` don't seem to be using the same base class to use polymorphism. Is there another way to do what I want without having two different loops in an if-else-structure? Of course I could create a function/lambda for the loop body or use some index arithmetic but is there a more elegant way?

The compiler complains about the assignment `it = vec.begin()` as they are different types. gcc and VC++ output different errors and seem to use different types for the return values of `vector::begin`.

Edit: The linked discussion/answer is not what I need(ed). I didn't want to convert a reverse iterator to a forward iterator but a way to hold either of them in the same variable. Or rather - as @Edgar Rokjān said - a uniform and elegant way to traverse a container in either direction.

With the new `std::ranges`, it also doesn't seem to work that easily. For example,

```cpp
    auto transformed =
        reverse ? vec | std::ranges::views::all : vec | std::ranges::views::reverse;
```

results in an error like

```
operands to '?:' have different types 'std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> >' and 'std::ranges::reverse_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> > >'
```

I guess, the most elegant solution is to throw the loop body into a lambda and then use it after deciding whether or not the traversion takes place in reverse order or not. I'll put up an answer including this, then.

Edit2: For anyone coming to this question and the linked "duplicate" doesn't help either, here is a possible solution that I find elegant enough.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
        bool reverse = true;
        
        auto do_my_thing = [&](const auto& elem) {
            cout << elem << ", ";
        };
    
        if (reverse) {
            std::for_each(vec.crbegin(), vec.crend(), do_my_thing);
        } else {
            std::for_each(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), do_my_thing);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037867/can-i-convert-a-reverse-iterator-to-a-forward-iterator

Comment: I don't think it is a dupe. The linked question is about conversion from reverse iterator to iterator, this question - about uniform way to traverse the container.

Comment: @Sven okay, cool. So what do you mean by it doesn't seem to use the same parent class? What's the error you're getting that makes you say that?

Comment: As suggested/pondered in the question, I'd use a template lambda like `[](auto it, auto end_it) { for(; it != end_it; ++it) cout << *it << ", ";`.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I edited my question a bit. I switched to repl.it  as a small testing environment and now I see that VC and gcc have different errors but both because of incompatible types.