# C++ : Implementing bidirectional iterator of B-tree

Tags: c++, tree, iterator

I'm implementing a bidirectional iterator of my B-Tree implementation. (Full code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/i4UeEvE3OB6mVup3)

In short, I'm stuck in reversing the direction.

Node implementation:

```
class Node {
        std::size_t n = 0;
        bool leaf = true;
        Node* parent = nullptr;
        std::size_t index = 0;
        std::vector<T> key;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> child;
        // details ...
};
```

My correct forward iterator implementation:

```
    class BTreeIterator {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        // using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        
        Node* node;
        std::vector<T>::iterator it;
        
        void Increment() {
            if (it == node->key.end()) {
                return;
            }
            if (node->leaf) {
                ++it;
                while (node->parent && it == node->key.end()) {
                    it = node->parent->key.begin() + node->index;
                    node = node->parent;
                }
            } else {
                auto i = std::distance(node->key.begin(), it);
                node = node->child[i + 1]->LeftmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.begin();
            }
        }
        
    public:
        BTreeIterator(Node* node, std::size_t i) : node {node} {
            assert(node && i <= node->key.size());
            it = node->key.begin() + i;
        }
        
        reference operator*() const {
            return *it;
        }
        
        pointer operator->() const {
            return it;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator operator++(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }
        
        friend bool operator==(const BTreeIterator& x, const BTreeIterator& y) {
            return x.node == y.node && x.it == y.it;
        }
        
        friend bool operator!=(const BTreeIterator& x, const BTreeIterator& y) {
            return !(x == y);
        }
    };
```

My failed attempt to implement `operator--`:

```
// ...
        void Decrement() {
            if (it == node->key.rend()) {
                return;
            }
            if (node->leaf) {
                --it;
                while (node->parent && it == node->key.rend()) {
                    it = node->parent->key.rbegin() + (node->getN() - node->index);
                    node = node->parent;
                }
            } else {
                auto i = std::distance(node->key.rbegin(), it);
                node = node->child[getN() - i - 1]->RightmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.rbegin();
            }
        }
// ...
        BTreeIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator operator--(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }
```

Because `it` is `std::vector<T>::iterator`, it fails to assign `.rbegin()` or `.rend()` of `std::vector<T>`, which is `std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator`.

Is there any way to get the address of pointer of `std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator` to make a `std::vector<T>::iterator`? I really need "before-one-the-begin" address to make ease `Decrement()` implementation.

Comment: There is no magic behind a reverse iterator. Internally, a reverse iterator holds a normal iterator (see `base()` member function). But that iterator `it` points to the element *after* the current element. That is, when you dereference a reverse iterator, you do `*std::prev(it)`. You can't have an iterator one element before `begin()`. This is not allowed by the standard.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037867/can-i-convert-a-reverse-iterator-to-a-forward-iterator

Comment: Fine, I've done the job with using ```begin()``` only. It was just like a mediocre algorithm textbook problem, I was too scared for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer: I cannot get before-one-the-begin in any way.

I have to just implement it differently.

Correct implementation of `Decrement()`:

```
void Decrement() {
            auto i = std::distance(node->key.begin(), it);
            if (!node->leaf) {
                node = node->child[i]->RightmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.begin() + node->key.size() - 1;
            } else {
                if (i > 0) {
                    --it;
                } else {
                    while (node->parent && node->index == 0) {
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                    if (node->index > 0) {
                        it = node->parent->key.begin() + node->index - 1;
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: How is your `std::distance` defined? Isn't it an O(n) operation?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It's not, ```node->key``` is ```std::vector<T>```

Comment: Oh so it's a distance within the node, haven't noticed that.