# Iterating in reverse direction using rbegin() and begin()

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, stdvector, reverse-iterator

When we are iterating in reverse direction, I see that most people use the following structure:

```
for (auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); it++)
{
    // block of code //
}
```

But for a long time, I have a doubt about using this, and I want to know why the following code does not work.

As we know, the last element will have the highest index than any element index in the array, and the array is going to take contiguous memory.

My primary doubt is when iterating backwards, why shouldn't we use `it--`?

I want the reason why the following code is not going to work. I am running the loop from `rbegin`, that is the last element, and I am going until the first element. I am decrementing `it` by one in every iteration.

```
for (auto it = vec.rbegin(); it >= vec.begin(); it--)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Even the below code is not working, why?

```
for(auto it = vec.rbegin(); it >= vec.begin(); it++)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Comment: ++ is the operator to use to advance iterators, even backward ones. You go back one extra step (thus ++).  Note in C++20 you can also use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view which might make more sense to you

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you think `FOR(auto it=vec.rbegin();it>=arr.begin();it++)` would work?  `FOR` - is that a macro? `vec` and `arr` ? Comparing a reverse iterator with a normal iterator?

Comment: You can understand `rbegin()` as a data struct of a special pointer such that `++` operator would be overloaded into `--`.  And in all, it is just a design issue. If you used it more, you might realize such a uniform design has many benefits in use.

Comment: You'd better not compare `rbegin()` pointer with `begin()` cause they are different things.  Thinking about a list `{1,2}`,  `begin()` points to 1, `rbegin()` points to 2, `end()` points to the position **after** 2, `rend()` points to the position **before** 1

Comment: [std::rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [std::rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend) and for `std::vector` specifically [std::vector::rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) and [std::vector::rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend) Plain-Jane vanilla C++ since C++11 (C++14 for general non-vector iterators)

Comment: @Peicherla Asrith Varma, a workable demo was in my solution's edit history. Hope it helps.

Comment: "not working" is not very useful in describing the issue. You should read the compiler error message, usually it holds a lot of useful information. If you dont understand the error message, no problem, include it in the question then others can explain

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in the given codes, the for loop's conditions are making issue due to type-mismatch.

The `vec.rbegin()` gives the `std::vector::reverse_iterator`, and the `vec.begin()` gives the `std::vector::iterator`; **those are different types** and can not be compared. Hence, you get compiler errors in those places.

---

> When iterating backwards, why shouldn't we use `it--`?

See the following reference picture from [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)

[image]

When you use `rbegin()`, you start from the last element. In order to advance further (like every iterator implementation) it uses the `operator++`. Advance here means, iterating backwards direction, because the starting point is the last element. Therefore, you should be using `it++` or `++it` instead.

---

For the last for loop example, however, there is only a type-mismatch issue. Using <sup>✱</sup>[`std::reverse_iterator::base()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base), you could get/ convert the reverse iterator to the corresponding base iterator, and it can be compared with the `vec.begin()`.

That means the following change will make it work:

```
for (auto it = vec.rbegin(); it.base() != vec.begin(); ++it)
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   std::cout << *it << " ";
}
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P4811471v)

---

**Side Note**:

- Even though, the above is possible, I would strongly suggest use the same iterators for comparison, which provides the code more natural look, and easy to understand for the fellow devs and less error-prone.
- <sup>✱</sup>Read more: [Can I convert a reverse iterator to a forward iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037867/can-i-convert-a-reverse-iterator-to-a-forward-iterator)

Answer (score 0):

In all, it is just a design issue, the designer designed the `begin`, `rbegin`, `end`, `rend` in that way.

Take an example of a container with three elements `{1,2,3}`.

- `begin()` points to `1`, `end()` points to the position **after** `3`
- `rbegin()` points to `3`,  `rend()` points to the position **before** `1`.

You can **understand** `rbegin()` as a special data struct of a special pointer (aka `iterator`) such that `+` operator would be overloaded into `-`.

You **can but not recommended** to mix `rbegin()` with `begin()` cause they are different things. And mixing is always error-prone for most of the time.

Comment: That's just for a demo. showing the `begin()` and `rbegin()` . It does not mean to show base usage. The purpose of the above example is not show the correct way, it just for comparing and showing the idea of my description. Thanks @JeJo

Answer (score 0):

*Reverse* iterators are designed to mimic *forward* iterators (and iterators in general are designed to mimic pointers), so algorithms can be written in an agnostic way that works with both types. All iterators advance with `operator++` and decrement with `operator--` , where

- *forward* iterators *advance* in a forward direction and *decrement* in a backwards direction
- *reverse* iterators *advance* in a backward direction and *decrement* in a forward direction

Comment: Yes but i have also written it++ for reverse iterator as well separately but the code is not working yet and my exact doubt is that i am starting from vec.rbegin() ie the last element and going till vec.begin() which is the first element but the code is not running ,pls clarify this doubt for me.

Comment: @PeicherlaAsrithVarma as others have already pointed out, you are mixing different types of iterators, which is *undefined behavior*. When using `rbegin()`, you need to iterate towards `rend()` instead of `begin()`. They are NOT the same thing. Have you read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator yet?