# Reverse Iterator points to the wrong point

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to reverse iterate through a map of type :

```
0 3 7 10 15
```

I need to reverse iterate through this map starting from 10 back to the start:

```
for(map<unsigned int, Object*>::reverse_iterator rit(mapA.find(10)); rit != mapA.rend(); ++rit) {
    cout << rit->first << endl;
}
```

However, I got the following:

```
7 3 0
```

May I know what is wrong with this iteration?

Comment: what result/behavior do you expect?

Comment: The note in the accepted answer here may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787293/get-a-reverse-iterator-from-a-forward-iterator-without-knowing-the-value-type

Comment: I would expect 10 7 3 0 to return. I read from cplusplus.com that "the reversed version does not point to the same element in the range, but to the one preceding it". How would I point to the same element?

Comment: @RetiredNinja nailed it.

Comment: Well, if you know how the iterator position will change when you reverse it then you know where to position it to account for that.

Comment: Problem is, I need to be able to iterate from 10 all the way to 0, because I need to perform some functions with the Object that is allocated with number 10.

Comment: @Todd `rit--`. But since the documentation says "the reversed version does not point to the same element in the range, but to the one preceding it", why are you surprised that *it indeed does so?*

Answer (score 0):

Forward iterators and reverse iterators correspond one-to-one. The forward iterator sequence has an "after the end" iterator (`end`) and the reverse iterator sequence has a "before the beginning" iterator (`rend`).

Since `find` returns a forward iterator, you are converting the forward iterator to its corresponding reverse iterator, This cannot point to the same place because otherwise the "after the end" iterator would have nothing to correspond to.

Consider a map with elements 1->`0`, 2->`3`, 3->`7`, 4->`10`, and 5->`15`.

The forward iterators are 1->`0`, 2->`3`, 3->`7`, 4->`10`, 5->`15`, 6->`end`.

The reverse iterators are: 1->`rend`, 2->`0`, 3->`3`, 4->`7`, 5->`10`, 6->`15`.

So the reverse iterator corresponding to forward iterator 10 is 7. They are both the fourth iterator in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A reverse iterator is defined as an adaptor around a bidirectional iterator.
The first reverse iterator of a container is reverse_iterator(container.end())
The last reverse iterator of a container is reverse_iterator(container.begin())
Dereferencing a reverse iterator holding a bidirectional iterator 'current'
is equivalent to:

```
deref_tmp = current;
--deref_tmp;
return *deref_tmp;
```

Hence (using a set here):

```
int main() {
    typedef std::set<int> Set;
    Set set = { 0, 3, 7, 10, 15 };
    Set::const_iterator forward = set.find(10);
    if(forward != set.end()) {
        for(Set::const_reverse_iterator backward = Set::const_reverse_iterator(++forward);
            backward != set.rend();
            ++backward)
        std::cout << *backward << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```